# Store html page in liferay

Tags: liferay

How to store html page in liferay and get a href link to the html page. I have some old html pages and I dont want to recreate as theme css are different.Please guide.

Comment: Can you please elaborate a little more on your question? It is not exactly clear as to what you want to do and why?

Comment: I have some html pages from my old site. I have top navigation in my present website beside that themes is applied on all the pages.If I paste content in WCD I have to embed the WCD in a page which will get the default theme.So better is I find a way to store Html page and give link to the html page.So please tell me where to store and get url for the stored page.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to create a folder in `$LIFERAY_HOME/webapps/html` (for example) and put your html pages there. So you can link any page in your domain, like:

```
www.yourdomain.com/html/page-you-want-to-display.html
```

Comment: Hey thanks for reply jdriesner it worked but my rich text box of WCD becomes uneditable when i place folder in webapps. When I delete the folder I again can see WCD rich text box to edit.